# trying to unit test a function inside react es6 component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

So I know if Im using createClass I can access a helper function with prototype:

```
  import React from 'react';

  var ContactUsRoot = React.createClass({

    test: function(){
      return 'yes';
    },
    render: function(){
      return (
        <div id='contact-us-wall'>
          <h6>Contact us</h6>
          <p>Please free feel to contact us with the following contact information</p>
        </div>)
    }

  })
  export default ContactUsRoot;
```

test.js:

```
import Contact from 'Contact.js';

describe('Helper functions in contactUsComponent', function(){
  var renderedNode;

  it('should return yes', function(){
        assert.equal(Contact.prototype.test(), 'yes');// look here
  });
```

But how do I access a helper function inside a es6 react component?

`class ContactUsRoot extends React.Component{` Do I have to create an instance then access from that instance or something? that doesn't sound right though

---

EDIT:
@CH Buckingham:

in test:

```
  var renderedElement = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Provider store = {store}><GraphRoot/></Provider>);

  april = renderedElement.getDays(3, 2016, "13");
```

actual component:

```
  class GraphRoot extends React.Component{
 [...]

 getDays(month, year, days){
 [...]
 return item;
 }
```

The rendering part worked perfectly, but when I try to access a method with `renderedElement.getDays(3, 2016, "13");`, it's saying it's not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update for your edits:

```
var theProviderInstance = reactUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Provider><MyComponent/></Provider>);
var theMyComponentInstance = reactUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(theProviderInstance, MyComponent);
theMyComponentInstance.someInstanceMethod();
```

//=====
You won't be able to access that instance method on your react component via the class prototype.

In the truest React unit test environment, you'd be rendering your react components into a fake DOM, like jsdom, and then using a reference to them to conduct your tests. Using utilities like: `'react-addons-test-utils'` and `renderIntoDocument`.

But technically, if you just wanted to test a simple method, and you didn't want it to be a global, or an exported function that the class has closure over, and you didn't care that it wouldn't have real access to real react environments, then you could just: `const fakeInstance = new ContactUsRoot()` and `fakeInstance.test()`

Comment: I'm using react test utils and jsDom too, but I thought it is used to test the rendering part only, I don't get how I can access a helper function inside the component with that. I do want to stick to `truest react unit test envior`, since Im doing this mainly for learning, please advice

Comment: renderIntoDocument will return a react component instance. You can then call any of its methods for testing.

Comment: Yea I've tried that but it gave me typeerror: `is not a function` I've edited the post to show the code

Comment: In your new example you pass the redux provider in as the containing component, so that's the reference you are now holding. Then you would use the test Utils find or scry, passing in the provider and your component class to get the reference to your component.

Comment: Just a note that with Enzyme you can use [`wrapper.instance().test()`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/instance.html) to access the function.

Answer (score 0):

Since the class syntax is nothing but syntactic sugar for the following structure (plus some further semantics)...

```
function ContactUsRoot() {
   ...
}

ContactUsRoot.prototype.test = function() {
    return 'yes';
 }
```

...you should be able to access the *test* function using the following as well:

```
ContactUsRoot.prototype.test();
```

So in your case, you should be able to reuse your existing test code.